# MySQL memory usage crashing server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I just want to preface this with the fact I am new to server admin work like this, but am very interested and eager to learn. I'm hosting a small WordPress site on Digital Ocean, the site is relatively new and has little to no traffic. The droplet is running a typical LAMP stack and has 1GB memory, which in my experience has been sufficient in the past as I tend to not use a lot of plugins and use fairly light themes. The only plugin I installed that I haven't used before is WordFence. Anyways, during development, I occasionally get an error that reads "Error establishing connection to the DB", sometimes the site will not load at all  and connecting via SSH is super sluggish. Today I experienced the issue and after it resolved itself, I SSH'd in to see what I can find. Below is what I was able to gather:

`top` constantly list mysql up top as it's usage is high

`1724 mysql     20   0 1333488 405436      0 S   0.7  40.5   0:11.53 mysqld`

`grep -Ei 'oom|out of memory' /var/log/syslog`

```
Jan 25 15:18:40 droplet kernel: [599977.961722]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Jan 25 15:18:40 droplet kernel: [599977.961936] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jan 25 15:18:40 droplet kernel: [599977.962031] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysql.service,task=mysqld,pid=31337,uid=112
Jan 25 15:18:40 droplet kernel: [599977.962130] Out of memory: Killed process 31337 (mysqld) total-vm:1342776kB, anon-rss:439804kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:112 pgtables:1264kB oom_score_adj:0
Jan 25 15:18:40 droplet kernel: [599978.039990] oom_reaper: reaped process 31337 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Jan 25 15:26:50 droplet kernel: [600468.028506] systemd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jan 25 15:26:50 droplet kernel: [600468.028534]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
Jan 25 15:26:50 droplet kernel: [600468.028658] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Jan 25 15:26:50 droplet kernel: [600468.028754] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysql.service,task=mysqld,pid=67924,uid=112
Jan 25 15:26:50 droplet kernel: [600468.028885] Out of memory: Killed process 67924 (mysqld) total-vm:1310584kB, anon-rss:385228kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:112 pgtables:1132kB oom_score_adj:0
Jan 25 15:26:50 droplet kernel: [600468.092875] oom_reaper: reaped process 67924 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Being new to this, I'm unsure if this is of concern (possibly an attack of some sort) or if it's simply a configuration Digital Ocean's 1-click WordPress install does or possibly that 1GB of memory isn't enough anymore. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are all the components in that single droplet?  Or is MySQL in its own droplet?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames Everything is in one droplet - PHP 8.0, MySQL8, Apache2, Ubuntu20.04 and WordPress. Running ```mysql> SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size``` gave me 134217728.

Comment: I think you will have to get a bigger droplet.  That's too much to squeeze into one droplet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in MySQL but I've spent a bit of time reducing MySQL 8.0 memory usage on a non-critical personal server I run and it's working fine. Others may post better answers - go with them over this.

I run an AWS EC2 t3a.nano server with five Wordpress instances, MySQL 8.x., PHP 7.x, and a couple of other things with 512MB RAM and 1GB swap, so 1GB is plenty for a low volume site. You can add some swap space if you like, your OS will page out data it doesn't need so that running processes have more RAM available.

You need to configure MySQL to run with limited memory, things like reducing RAM sizes, buffers, and turning off performance schema. Reducing PHP RAM usage will also help reduce the chance of out of memory killer kicking in. MySQL 8.0 still uses a lot more RAM than MySQL 5.6, though an expert may be able to reduce it more than I have.

Here's the key parts from my MySQL 8 config - noting here that I'm not an expert on MySQL and you should do some research to understand this configuration before applying it. Some of these might be the defaults, but I generally set most parameters near their lowest allowable value.

Your config files might be in different locations. Make sure you take a backup ideally of the whole server before starting any changes, and back up your files before you change them.

**/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf**

```
# global settings
performance_schema = OFF

innodb_buffer_pool_size=50M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size=1048576
innodb_log_file_size=4194304
innodb_max_undo_log_size=10485760
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K
innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
innodb_max_undo_log_size=10485760
max_connections=20
key_buffer_size=1M

# per-thread settings
thread_stack=140K
thread_cache_size = 2
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=128K
temptable_max_ram=2097152
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
```

**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**

```
key_buffer_size         = 16M
thread_stack            = 256K
```

Here's some tweaks I did to the PHP config to reduce RAM usage

**/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
pm.max_children = 3
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 1
pm.process_idle_timeout = 20s;
pm.max_requests = 50
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 64M
```

**Server Stats**

Here's a few stats from the servers 'top' command

Overall

- Mem 448MB, 42MB free, 190MB used, 216MB buffer / cache
- Swap 1024, 725MB free, 300MB used

Processes

- MySQL Virt 1459020 Res 44696 CPU 3% Mem 10%
- PHP FPM 7.x Virt 223124 Res 32464 CPU 0% Mem 7%
- Nginx Virt 63932 Res 7520 CPU 0% Mem 2%